# Objective-C module.modulemap file broke compilation if module has "-" in name, e.g. "Boring-gRPC"

Tags: objective-c, xcode, firebase, cocoapods, swift-package-manager

I have Objective-C project with cocoapods. When I add to Firebase SDK according to [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/installation-methods?hl=en&authuser=1#swift-package-manager) via SPM (or via CP) I got this error while compilation:

[image]

As I understand it is happening because of "-" in module name. If I don't add Firestore module, then Boring-gRPC not integrated and everything is works fine.

Xcode Version 14.2 (14C18)

Cocoapods 1.12.1

Comment: Hi Robert, could you share what Firebase version you are using? Additionally, are you able to share a minimum reproducible example? Feel free to file an issue on GitHub using this [template](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&template=BUG_REPORT.yml). Thanks!